# UICollectionView top cells disappear while animating keyboard appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have UICollectionView with cells inside. Everything works well except one thing.

During keyboard appearance animation, top cells that are about to go offscreen just disappear in place without any animation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMt6DiJD5KU

I have tried to implement `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem` but it has no any effect.
Also tried to expand rect in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let rect = CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY - 312, width: rect.width, height: rect.height + 312)
    return itemAttributesCache.filter { $0.frame.intersects(rect) }
}
```

but also with no luck.

The only working solution that i found is to expand `UICollectionView.frame` above the screen to the keyboard height and set `UICollectionView.contentInset.top` to the keyboard height. It works but absolutely ugly.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: check this repo
https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout

Comment: `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem` is called for cells corresponding to items removed from the collection view, not for cells going out of screen. It will be easier to help you if you can provide a sample project with the layout implementation and the issue happening.

Comment: Are you using any SDK like IQKeyboardManager to handle your keyboard action ?

Answer (score -1):

To have a proper keyboard appearance in your collection view:

1) Get the size of keyboard.

2) Adjust the bottom content inset of collection view by keyboard height.

3) Scroll the target text field into view.

You need to register for keyboard changing notifications.
(keyboardWillHideNotification and keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification)

Use notification center:

Inside class:

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)

@objc func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardScreenEndFrame = keyboardValue.cgRectValue
        let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)

        if notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide {
            collectionView.contentInset = .zero
        } else {
            collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, right: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Reset the content inset when keyboard dismissed.
I'm using textField delegate method.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("returned")
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

For more details, please refer these links:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

and

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-adjust-a-uiscrollview-to-fit-the-keyboard